# can't compare user input with number, nasm elf64

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I swear I've read more than 20 pages today, from NASM's manual to Universities' guides to Wikipedia to everything in between but I just can't wrap my head around this, I wrote a single program to compare the user input with either a 0 or a 1 and then act based on that (I should probably use an array once I get the hang of them in Assembly), but this will do for now.

Problem is, **my checks never work**, they always go straight to the err label, I looked at [x86 NASM Assembly - Problems with Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073996/x86-nasm-assembly-problems-with-input) which seemed similar but it wasn't quite the same, I really don't need to store the user's input, just check what it was and react on it.

Here's a reduce version of my code, it's supposed to exit after two consecutive 0's have been entered, clearly I haven't been able to test it, since I can't figure out what the user entered.

I'm sorry if this is a silly question but this week Assembly has gotten the best of me.

```
; constants
section .data
  lblZero:      db    'Zero';
  lblOne:       db    'One ';
  lblNumLength: db    0x4;
  tmp:          db    0;

; code
section .text
  global _start

; linker needs this, 'main'
_start:

loop:
  ; user was already prompted for a single digit
  ; store user's input ; read
  mov rax, 0 ;
  mov rbx, 19 ;
  mov rcx, tmp ;
  mov rdx, 10 ;
  syscall
  ; series of IFs
  cmp   rcx, 0    ; is input 0? 00 exits the program
  je    isZero
  cmp   rcx, 1    ; is input 1?
  je    isOne  
  jmp   exit  

; user typed 0
isZero:
  inc   rcx               ; flag for 0
  cmp   rcx, 2            ; checking if this is the 2nd zero
  je    exit              ; if so, we are outta here
  mov   rsi, lblZero ;
  mov   rcx, -1 ;
  jmp  print ;

; user typed 1
isOne:
  mov   rsi, lblOne ;
  mov   rcx, -1 ;
  jmp  print ;

; prints the string into the screen ; sys_write
print:
  mov   rax, 1 ;           
  mov   rdi, 1 ;         
  mov   rdx, lblNumLength ;       
  syscall
  jmp   loop

; displays an error message
err:
  ; sys_write, not relevant to the Q     
  syscall
  jmp loop

; shutsdown program ; sys_write ; sys_exit
exit:
  ; not relevant to the Q, code always ends here
```

I read here http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~if817/arquivos/asmtut/index.html#stack that the input is not truly an int, but a character, so I tried creating variables that just store '1' or '0' but nothing seems to do the trick.

I'm a super new to Assembly so if I'm doing really stupid here, I would appreciate if you point it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to run this on 64 bit AMD64 linux, you need to make sure you use the right way of passing parameters to the kernel (the calling convention).

For a 64 bit app on linux/x64, it is as follows:

- **rax** - system call id
- **rdi** - argument 1
- **rsi** - argument 2
- **rdx** - argument 3
- **r10** - argument 4
- arg 5 and 6 are in **r9** and **r8**
- **rcx** and **r11** values are not preserved across syscall, but all other registers will not be clobbered.

In addition, Paul R's answer is also correct. The ASCII representation of '0' is not decimal zero. Another gotcha is that the stdin operates in buffered mode by default, so you won't actually get any data until you press enter. The code below reads two bytes into the tmp buffer (pointed to by rsi) and compares the first with ascii-zero. The second byte is a newline character that we're not particularly interested in.

```
; constants
section .data
  lblZero:      db    'Not zero, try again', 0xa;
  tmp:          db    0,0;
; code

section .text
BITS 64
  global _start
_start: 
  mov rax, 0   ; sys_read(int fd, void *ptr, int count)
  mov rdi, 0   ; 0 = stdin 
  mov rsi, tmp ; @ tmp
  mov rdx, 2   ; 2 bytes (one for our number, another to store newline)
  syscall
  cmp byte[rsi], '0' ; is input '0' (or decimal 48) ? 
  je  done
  mov rax, 1            ; sys_write(int fd, void *ptr, int count)
  mov rdi, 1            ; 1 = stdout
  mov rsi, lblZero      ; @lblZero
  mov rdx, 20           ; 20 bytes
  syscall
  jmp _start

done:   
  mov rax, 60 ; sys_exit
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall
```

Comment: Ok this was it, this is what led me into the right path, thank you very much Henrik!

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare *characters*, not integer values. Change:

```
cmp rcx,0
```

to

```
cmp byte [rcx],'0'
```

Ditto for the comparison with 1.

Comment: Make that `cmp byte [rcx], '0'`... but I don't think you've got the parameters in the right registers for a 64-bit system call. Seems to me that file descriptor should be in rsi, buffer (the address!) in rdi (so `cmp byte [rdi], '0'`), max length in rdx... but I'm still(!) running 32-bit hardware, so I could be rong. :)

Comment: I changed that but I'm still getting the same behavior, the program still ignores the checks and goes straight to the exit label :s, could there be something else that I'm missing?

Comment: See Frank's comments above - it looks like there might be a few other problems with the code that need fixing.

Comment: Hi Paul, what I picked up from Frank suggested to change everything into bytes and add quotes? I believed I tried that but didn't work, I put up a 50 points bounty in case you are interested to help me correct the code even further.

Comment: Paul, thank you very much, yours and Henrik's answer really help me solve this one!